# SQL Server - Join Duplicate And Cross Rows In A Row With Sum Up

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, multiple-columns

I have an SQL table, it has 250000+ rows and 3 columns. My table looks like that;

```
      Column 1     Column 2     Column 3
   ----------------------------------------
       Honda        Civic         500
       Civic        Honda         250
       Alfa         Romeo         1650000
       Alfa         Romeo         150000
       Renault      Broadway      10
       Aston        Martin        750
       Renault      Megane        2000
       Megane       Renault       150
       Ferrari      Enzo          88500
       Ferrari      Enzo          500
       Renault      Megane        30000
```

I want to do this, when I compile my code in SQL, my table should look like that;

```
      Column 1     Column 2     Column 3
   ---------------------------------------
       Honda        Civic         750
       Alfa         Romeo         1800000
       Renault      Broadway      10
       Aston        Martin        750
       Renault      Megane        32150
       Ferrari      Enzo          89000
```

Note: I'm not an SQL guy, so I couldn't produce an idea for it, sorry.

Comment: Why Honda Civit and not Civic Honda?

Comment: Is there a name for this type of question?   I know I've seen it a few times before.

Comment: @GordonLinoff actually it doesn't matter.

Comment: @TabAlleman I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky question.  I assume that when there is a pair, you want to keep the ordering of the pair with the higher sum:

```
with cc as (
       select column1, column2, sum(column3) as sum_column3
       from t
       group by column1, column2
      )
select (case when cc2.sum_column3 > cc.sum_column3 then cc2.column1 else cc.column1 end) as column1,
       (case when cc2.sum_column3 > cc.sum_column3 then cc2.column2 else cc.column2 end) as column2,
       (cc.sum_column3 + coalesce(cc2.sum_column3, 0)) as sum_column3
from cc left join
     cc cc2
     on cc.column1 = cc2.column2 and cc.column2 = cc2.column
where cc2.column1 is null or (cc.column1 < cc.column2);  -- keep only one row of pairs
```

So, this query starts by summarizing the data.  It then looks to see if the "reverse" row is in the data.  If so, it chooses the columns based on the ordering that is more prevalent.

Comment: I will try it. Thank you sir.